# SQL Find missing date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that holds all the days/months of the year

E.G.

```
Day      Month
1         9
2         9
3         9
4         9
5         9
6         9
7         9
...       ...
```

I have a table which shows the date ranges from different datasets

E.G.

```
 DataSet    DateRange
webshop 2013-09-20
webshop 2013-09-21
webshop 2013-09-22
webshop 2013-09-23
webshop 2013-09-24
webshop 2013-09-25
webshop 2013-09-26
webshop 2013-09-27
webshop 2013-09-28
webshop 2013-09-29
webshop 2013-09-30
```

How would I compare the two tables to show which days are missing from the DataSet for that particular month

E.G. for my example above where the dataset is `webshop` it is missing the date range 01/09/2013 - 19/09/2013

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the data type of *DateRange* column?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty thanks for helping out, it is `DATE`

Comment: ok, so you are going to check the missing dates for one month at a given time?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty yeah, just checking for one month at a time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use CTE and write a query as:

```
declare @StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE
set @StartDate = '2013-09-01';
set @EndDate = '2013-09-30';

  WITH DateRange(Date) AS
     (
         SELECT
             @StartDate Date
         UNION ALL
         SELECT
             DATEADD(day, 1, Date) Date
         FROM
             DateRange
         WHERE
             Date < @EndDate
     )

     SELECT 'webshop',Date 
     FROM DateRange
     EXCEPT 
     SELECT DataSet,DateRange
     FROM ImportedDateRange
     WHERE DataSet='webshop'
     --You could remove Maximum Recursion level constraint by specifying a MaxRecusion of zero
     OPTION (MaxRecursion 10000);
```

Comment: Ah, just one query, i have different datasets,dateranges in the same table, is there any way to specify only check `webshop` or any other datasets as a parameter?

Comment: @neeko: Put where condition to filter out only the *webshop* dates

Comment: @huMptyduMpty thanks again for your help, I'm guessing this would go in the second select statement?

Comment: @neeko: According to this answer it should be something like `SELECT DataSet,DateRange
     FROM ImportedDateRange WHERE DataSet='weblog'`

Comment: Probably not significant for such a small sequence, but just FYI [using recursive CTEs to generate a sequential dataset](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2) is probably the least efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

If you main table is

```
#Temp(Title varchar(10),DateRange date)
```

You can do like something like

```
CREATE TABLE #ALLDATE(Date1 date)
DECLARE @startDate DATE='9/1/2013'
DECLARE @endDate DATE='9/30/2013'

insert into #ALLDATE
SELECT [Date] = DATEADD(Day,Number,@startDate) 
FROM  master..spt_values 
WHERE Type='P'
AND DATEADD(day,Number,@startDate) <= @endDate


select 'webshop',Date1 
from #ALLDATE
where Date1 not in 
        (select DateRange from #Temp where Title='webshop' and MONTH(GETDATE())=9)
```