# why won't this query work properly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, right-join

my `MasterSales` table looks like this

```
SalesDate | Category | Total
----------------------------- 
1/1/2000    01          100 
1/1/2000    02          110
1/2/2000    01          80
1/2/2000    03          20
```

and my `Category` table looks like this

> ```
> ID | Name
> ----------
> 01 | A
> 02 | B
> 03 | C
> 04 | D
> ```

my query looks like this:

```
SELECT m.SalesDate, c.Name, SUM(ISNULL(m.Total,0)) AS TotalSales
FROM MasterSales m
LEFT JOIN Category c ON c.ID = m.Category
WHERE m.SalesDate BETWEEN '1/1/2000' AND '1/2/2000'
```

the result I want is like this:

```
SalesDate | Name | TotalSales
------------------------------
1/1/2000    A      100
1/1/2000    B      110
1/1/2000    C      0
1/1/2000    D      0
1/2/2000    A      80
1/2/2000    B      0
1/2/2000    C      20
1/2/2000    D      0
```

but the result I get looks this:

```
SalesDate | Name | TotalSales
------------------------------
1/1/2000    A      100
1/1/2000    B      110
1/2/2000    A      80
1/2/2000    C      20
```

I already tried using `RIGHT JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` and switching the table on `FROM` clause but the result is still the same. can anyone help explain to me why it won't work properly?

P.S. : I'm using SQL Server 2005 (if it matters)

Comment: add `GROUP BY m.SalesDate, c.Name` to the end of your query

Comment: What is the logic here ? How do you get the sale date for Category D as 01012000 and 01022000 ?

Comment: You are joining with the condition `c.ID = m.Category` so obviously `Name=D` wont get selected because `id=4` isn't available in the other table

Comment: @TinTran : I tried that too but the result is the same..

@SatheeshVariath Variath : I'm using `Between` in the query

@Gone : I thought by using `left join Category` all the data from `Category` will appear even though there's no match in the other table?

btw how do I add a breakline in the comment?

Comment: thank you so much to everyone who tried to help. I picked Darka's answer because it is the easiest one to try on management studio and it works perfectly (not that everyone else's is wrong, I just didn't try them all) :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

and here is my answer

```
WITH MasterSales (SalesDate, Category, Total) AS (
  SELECT       '1/1/2000','01',100
  UNION SELECT '1/1/2000','02',110
  UNION SELECT '1/2/2000','01',80
  UNION SELECT '1/2/2000','03',20
), Category (ID, Name) AS (
  SELECT       '01','A'
  UNION SELECT '02','B'
  UNION SELECT '03','C'
  UNION SELECT '04','D'
), getDates AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT SalesDate 
  FROM MasterSales 
  WHERE SalesDate BETWEEN '1/1/2000' AND '1/2/2000'
)

SELECT gD.SalesDate, C.Name, SUM(ISNULL(MS.Total,0)) AS TotalSales
FROM getDates AS gD
CROSS JOIN Category AS C
LEFT JOIN MasterSales AS MS 
    ON MS.Category = C.ID
    AND MS.SalesDate = gD.SalesDate 
GROUP BY gD.SalesDate, C.Name
```

Comment: I don't think this is somewhat good with all those static values

Comment: where u see static ?? its just example with cte nothing more ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this. This covers all dates where you have **MasterSales**.  In other words, this fills in the missing categories for the day.  However, you're looking to fill in missing dates as well, you'll need to create a **date** control table.. look into **[recursive cte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677472/sql-find-missing-date-ranges/20678491#20678491)** for the date table.

```
;with control_table as (
  select distinct SalesDate, ID
  from MasterSales ms
  cross join Category c
  where ms.SalesDate between '1/1/2000' AND '1/2/2000'
  )


select ct.SalesDate, c.Name as Category, coalesce(sum(ms.Total),0) as Total
from control_table ct
inner join Category c
  on ct.ID = c.ID
left join MasterSales ms
  on ct.SalesDate = ms.SalesDate
  and ct.ID = ms.Category
group by ct.SalesDate, c.Name
order by ct.SalesDate asc, c.Name asc
```

**[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5ba4/23)**

Comment: This is almost better than mine - you forgot `SUM`

Answer (score 1):

Finally, your problem is solved. Use this query:

```
SELECT AAA.SalesDate,AAA.Name,ISNULL(BBB.TotalSales,0) as TotalSales  
FROM (
    (SELECT m.SalesDate, c.Name
    FROM MasterSales m,Category c
    WHERE m.SalesDate BETWEEN '1/1/2000' AND '1/2/2000'
    GROUP BY m.SalesDate,c.Name) AAA

    LEFT JOIN 

    (SELECT m.SalesDate,c.Name, SUM(ISNULL(m.Total,0)) AS TotalSales
    FROM MasterSales m,Category c
    WHERE m.SalesDate BETWEEN '1/1/2000' AND '1/2/2000'
    AND c.ID=m.Category 
    GROUP BY m.SalesDate,c.Name) BBB 
    on AAA.SalesDate=BBB.SalesDate AND AAA.Name=BBB.Name)
```

**Explanation:**

The first part of the query (AAA) selects all combination of `SalesDate` and `Category`.

The second part of the query (BBB) selects `SalesDate`,`Category` and `TotalSales`.

And then we join both of them (AAA & BBB) on `SalesDate` and `Category`.

Works perfectly !!!. See [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4821/100).

Comment: I suspect this will lose in perfomance to my or sam yi solution

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**: changed the method of creating temp table using [`sam yi` logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22061031/2094094)

I suggest you create an addition table.

```
;WITH control_table AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT SalesDate, Name
        FROM MasterSales ms
             CROSS JOIN Category c
       )

SELECT d.SalesDate,
       c.name,
       COALESCE(sum(m.total),0) totalsales
  FROM control_table d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Category c
            ON d.Name = c.name
       LEFT OUTER JOIN MasterSales m
            ON (c.id = m.category
                AND d.SalesDate = m.salesdate)
WHERE d.SalesDate BETWEEN '1/1/2000' 
                      AND '1/2/2000'
GROUP BY 
       d.SalesDate,
       c.name
ORDER BY 
       d.SalesDate,
       c.name;
```

[Here is **SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92c97/8)

Comment: Create another table and insert all data into it? I don't think that is a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT cj.Date, cj.Name, IsNull(m.Total,0) Total
FROM (SELECT d.Date, c.Name, c.Id
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SalesDate Date 
          FROM MasterSales) d, Category c) cj
LEFT JOIN MasterSales m ON m.SalesDate = cj.Date 
  AND cj.Id = m.Category
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1344/3

Add your date-between conditions

And I'm sure there ate better ways to do this.

Cheers

Comment: why negative? did u even try? :(